# Работа js-плагина без настроек в html-странице

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня. Решил сделать сайт, но из-за моих интересных идей, пришлось использовать js-плагин.
Так суть в чем, js-плагины имеют настройки этого самого плагина. Выглядят они так:

```
//Вставляется в html-страницу, например
pluginName(".main", {
    firstOption: "true",
    secondOption: false
});
```

Так вот, я хочу убрать эти настройки плагина, полностью.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что изменить, что бы все работало без:

```
//Вставляется в html-страницу, например
pluginName(".main", {
    firstOption: "true",
    secondOption: false
});
```

Я так понял, что ".main" надо куда-то в js-файл записать, но куда?

Вот сам плагин:
http://pastebin.com/fgaydWae

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно убрать из html элемент с классом '.main' и содержимое скрипта.

Тогда вынесите вызов настроек в js файл и перед ними создайте '.main' элемент:

```
//В js файле
var main = document.createElement('div');
main.className = 'main';
document.body.appendChild(main); // Или найдите контейнер через document.querySelector('#containerId');

pluginName(".main", {
    firstOption: "true",
    secondOption: false
});
```

В html в конце body подключаете скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourJsFile.js"></script>
```

Comment: **вам нужно убрать из html элемент с классом '.main'** - нет, мне нужно убрать настройки плагина. Ладно, это сложно понять, а мне лень объяснять.